# Enable LSP in spacemacs only for certain languages?

Tags: spacemacs, lsp-mode, lsp

[The spacemacs LSP layer documentation](https://develop.spacemacs.org/layers/+tools/lsp/README.html) says:

> Enabling this layer will set the used backend for all supported languages to LSP unless you explicitly set a specific backend for the language.

I find this a problem because emacs often prompts me to install a language server (occasionally even trapping me in the minibuffer because of some bug), but I rarely feel the need to use LSP for a given language.  So if I want to use LSP even for one language, I have to configure it off for every other, file type by file type (that includes e.g. things like JSON files). That seems like a never-ending task.

Is there some way around this so that I can explicitly *enable* (whitelist) use of LSP instead of disable it (blacklist) for particular languages?

Comment: In the meantime, mind telling me how you've even managed to disable it per-language?

Comment: @DidierA. For python, in my `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers` I have: `(python :variables python-backend 'nope)` (the real values are `'anaconda` and `'lsp`)

Comment: @DidierA. For json, in my `dotspacemacs/user-config` I have: `(setq json-backend 'company-json)`